# Google Image chart not showing correct value for Y-axis in Bar chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I am rending image chart on a server side code. I am using bar chart (bvg).
I am not able to render the chart the way I want to. I am sure it's doable because I have done it using Google Chart JS. The chart's x axis is month and y axis is score. I want to display the labels Month and Score for each axis along with the bar labels. I also want to show the value markers on the Y-axis.

When I add X and Y axis labels with chxl the Axis Labels shows up along with Y-axis value markers; but strange the value markers denote wrong values. The values range between 0 and 100 no matter what values my bar represents and that too the height of the bar doesn't match with the Y-axis values (which ranges between 0 and 100). Please help.

I've written the URL like this:

[https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=bvg&chxt=x,x,y,y&chxl=1:|Months|3:|Score&chxp=1,50|3,50&chbh=30,20,20&chds=0,40&chs=400x400&chco=015CAE,015CAE,015CAE,015CAE,015CAE&chd=t:**22,32,11,27,8**&chl=Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=bvg&chxt=x,x,y,y&chxl=1:%7CMonths%7C3:%7CScore&chxp=1,50%7C3,50&chbh=30,20,20&chds=0,40&chs=400x400&chco=015CAE,015CAE,015CAE,015CAE,015CAE&chd=t:22,32,11,27,8&chl=Jan%7CFeb%7CMar%7CApr%7CMay)

And I am concerned about the values displayed in the following snapshot of the chart (see highlighted values in red, they do not match the actual bar values):

[image]

Comment: Can I expect some help on this question please?

Answer (score 1):

**Don't Include chds** parameter

Here is the modified link:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=bvg&chxt=x,x,y,y&chxl=1:|Months|3:|Score&chxp=1,50|3,50&chbh=30,20,20&chs=400x400&chco=015CAE,015CAE,015CAE,015CAE,015CAE&chd=t:22,32,11,27,8&chl=Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May
```